# How can I customize the generated xml in a web service call? ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, soap

Is it possible to change the autogenerated xml that is send in the SOAP call? if it is, how can I do it?.

I want to do this becouse my autogenerated xml does not work and I have to manually change some little details.

Thank you !

Comment: I would edit and rewrite this question not to be “is it possible” (because everything is possible) to rather “I have this code, it produces this output, but I would need it to be this way, how can I accomplish that?” Currently the only answer that can be given is “yes” and I’m sure that won’t help you.

Comment: Hello!
I have no code yet to show, I am just reseraching ways to do this!
Thank you!

Comment: One thing I ran into I'm the past with generated WSDL is it creates multi-file WSDL documents. I know with .NET 4.5 you could use the "?singleWsdl" query string to flatten the WSDL. Is that what your looking for?